# Insert lines after character

Tags: text-processing, xml

I have data in a long  lined file example:

```
<currency>USD</currency><amount>111</amount><amountf>111/amountf><recv_confirms>2</recv_confirms><fee>22</fee><feef>2222</feef><direction>incoming</direction><status>1050</status><sent_to></sent_to><send_txid></send_txid><checkout><type>button</type><invoice>8888</invoice><item_name>Name - Invoice #8888</item_name><src_currency>USD</src_currency><quantity>1</quantity><price_per_item>25.00000000</price_per_item><subtotal>25.00000000</subtotal><total>25.00000000</total>
```

I need this data to turn into the following:

```
<currency>USD</currency>
<amount>111</amount>
<amountf>111/amountf>
<recv_confirms>2</recv_confirms>
<fee>22</fee>
<feef>2222</feef>
<direction>incoming</direction>
<status>1050</status>
<sent_to></sent_to>
<send_txid></send_txid>
<checkout>
<type>button</type>
<invoice>8888</invoice>
<item_name>Name - Invoice #8888</item_name>
<src_currency>USD</src_currency>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<price_per_item>25.00000000</price_per_item>
<subtotal>25.00000000</subtotal>
<total>25.00000000</total>
```

There are lines like `<checkout>` that have no data which don't include a `/`

How could I go about doing this? Preferably with either `sed` or `perl`

Comment: This looks like a _fragment_ of an XML document (no root node, missing closing tags). Do you have the the rest of the document available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E 's;<([^/]);\n<\1;2g' file

<currency>USD</currency>
<amount>111</amount>
<amountf>111/amountf>
<recv_confirms>2</recv_confirms>
<fee>22</fee>
<feef>2222</feef>
<direction>incoming</direction>
<status>1050</status>
<sent_to></sent_to>
<send_txid></send_txid>
<checkout>
<type>button</type>
<invoice>8888</invoice>
<item_name>Name - Invoice #8888</item_name>
<src_currency>USD</src_currency>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<price_per_item>25.00000000</price_per_item>
<subtotal>25.00000000</subtotal>
<total>25.00000000</total>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest using a tool to indent your xml file

```
xmllint -format -recover nonformatted.xml > formatted.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

A little `sed` golfing stepping off from @guillermochamorro to avoid the first line breaking

```
sed -E 's;([^^])(<[^/]);\1\n\2;g' file1
```